# How to install Mac OS Sierra in virtual box on Linux Mint 19

Tags: osx, virtualbox, dual-boot, virtual-machine

I have been trying to follow instructions from an online source (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTnn4BrpJro), but seem to run into problems when I want to boot the Sierra on the virtual machine.

After creating the VM Sierra in VB, I added the image as a separate hard disk. Then when launching it, it freezes the installation.

I successfully created a VM for my Linux mint to play around with new programs.

If someone has easy instructions it will be much appreciated. Unfortunately, I need the Sierra VM to run a specific software.